# Select records within 5 kilometers with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have an application that uses coordinates. I want to select records within 5 km that were thrown in the last 5 minutes. How can I do this easiest? I want to write a procedure. The values I will send to the procedure are latitude (float 11,8) and longitude (float 11,8).

Example table:

```
id   car_id   lati   longi   created_at
1      15      xx      yy    2021-04-19 12:00:00
2      16      xx      yy    2021-04-19 13:00:00
3      15      xx      yy    2021-04-19 15:00:00
```

I found a query like this but can't use group by.

```
SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians("xx.xxx") ) * cos( radians( lati ) ) * cos( radians( longi ) - radians("yy.yyy") ) + sin( radians("xx.xxx") ) * sin( radians( lati ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM mobil_gps 
where created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 minute)
HAVING distance < 5;
```

EDIT:

For example. I am a customer and want to see the locations of vehicles within 5 km.

Comment: Why do you need a group by in your query? What do you expect it to do? What's wrong with the query in your question? It seems to give you the records within 5 km where the record was created in the last 5 minutes.

Comment: As a result of the query, I create a marker on the map. I want to solve the problem in the procedure instead of doing extra processing in php-laravel for each car. @Shadow

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: I still do not get why you need group by here. Group by is used for aggregation. For example you can get the count vehicles that are within the 5 km radius of a coordinate and checked in the last 5 minutes. Your question does not mention aggregation at all, it just talks about listing records that meet certain criteria.

Comment: mine suggestion is to provide some better example data and obfuscate the real customer lati   longi with locations which are sea or desert locations for example and provide expected results based on the example data.

Comment: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_distance_sphere/) to calculate the distance between two points that are on a sphere.

The example from the MariaDB KB:

```
SET @zenica   = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(17.907743 44.203438)');
SET @sarajevo = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(18.413076 43.856258)');
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(@zenica, @sarajevo);

55878.59337591705
```

If you're interested in the distance on a plane, use [ST_DISTANCE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_distance/).

Answer (score -1):

You can eliminate the `HAVING` clause from your query by nesting it, like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM (
     SELECT *, big_fat_formula AS distance 
       FROM mobil_gps 
      where created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 minute)
  ) mdist
 WHERE distance < 5;
```

So, if you want to do some sort of GROUP BY aggregation, you can do it on the outer query.

```sql
SELECT vehicle_type, MIN(distance)nearest, COUNT(*)no_of_vehicles
  FROM (
     SELECT *, big_fat_formula AS distance 
       FROM mobil_gps 
      where created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 minute)
  ) mdist
 WHERE distance < 5
 GROUP BY vehicle_type
 ORDER BY MIN(distance);
```

You didn't ask about this, but you can make your query a whole lot faster by using a [bounding box filter](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/) to avoid running the distance computation on many rows. In your application, an index on `mobil_gps (created_at, lati, longi)` will help the bounding-box filter.

And, the distance formula itself is a good candidate to be made into a [stored function](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/vicenty-great-circle-distance-formula/).

Note: the `3959` constant in your formula yields *statute miles".  For km, use `6362`